# Trying to retrieve all rows from local H2 database with Quarkus

Tags: kotlin, orm, h2, quarkus

I'm creating a Quarkus project in Kotlin. I'm trying to implement an API where I hit "/users" endpoint, and it returns all the users I have in my local database.

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error. The stacktrace:

```
The stacktrace below has been reversed to show the root cause first. 

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "USER0_.CREATEDAT" not found; SQL statement:
select user0_.id as id1_7_, user0_.createdAt as createda2_7_, user0_.email as email3_7_, user0_.fullName as fullname4_7_, user0_.updatedAt as updateda5_7_ from User user0_ [42122-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:150)
    at org.h2.expression.Alias.optimize(Alias.java:51)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:858)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:283)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:304)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.list(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:239)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.kotlin.runtime.PanacheQueryImpl.list(PanacheQueryImpl.java:154)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.kotlin.runtime.KotlinJpaOperations.list(KotlinJpaOperations.java:24)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.kotlin.runtime.KotlinJpaOperations.list(KotlinJpaOperations.java:10)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.listAll(AbstractJpaOperations.java:289)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.domain.adapters.databases.panache.UserRepository.listAll(UserRepository.kt)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.domain.adapters.databases.panache.UserRepository_Subclass.listAll$$superaccessor28(UserRepository_Subclass.zig:4915)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.domain.adapters.databases.panache.UserRepository_Subclass$$function$$28.apply(UserRepository_Subclass$$function$$28.zig:29)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:63)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.domain.adapters.databases.panache.UserRepository_Subclass.listAll(UserRepository_Subclass.zig:4873)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.domain.adapters.databases.panache.UserRepository_ClientProxy.listAll(UserRepository_ClientProxy.zig:1353)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.rest.UsersResource.getAllUsers(UserResource.kt:24)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.rest.UsersResource_Subclass.getAllUsers$$superaccessor2(UsersResource_Subclass.zig:354)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.rest.UsersResource_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(UsersResource_Subclass$$function$$2.zig:29)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:63)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at com.fortuneapp.backend.application.rest.UsersResource_Subclass.getAllUsers(UsersResource_Subclass.zig:312)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:138)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
Resulted in: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 78 more
Resulted in: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1602)
    ... 62 more
Resulted in: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    ... 18 more
```

I've set up my local H2 database connection by adding this to my application.yaml file:

```
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: h2
    username: sa
    jdbc:
      url: "jdbc:h2:mem:default"
  flyway:
    migrate-at-start: true
```

Furthermore, I'm using https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache, which is quite easy to use. I've created a User entity, and a User repository in my project. I then use those in my User resource, where I define the api.

```
@Path("/users")
class UsersResource {

    @Inject
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getAllUsers() : GetAllUsersResponse =
         try {
             GetAllUsersSuccess(userRepository.listAll())
        } catch (e: NotFoundException) {
             GetAllUsersFailure(e)
        }

}
```

I've already implemented Flyway, for my database migration. This seems to go well. I'm also adding a row to the table when the migration runs, and I can see that "1 row is affected", so I think Flyway has access to the H2 database.

Do any of you guys know what I'm missing?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you add the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the qn.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I defined my column names in snake case, while my entity properties where defined in camel case.